# how do i change topic name for ar_pose?

Tags: ros, ar-pose, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, ar_pose package looks for Image data published by usb_cam, but I would like it to look for Image data published by a different node (ar_drone).  Is there a way to change the topic source without hacking the source code for ar_pose?

I notice that ar_kinect must do something similar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10033/how-do-i-change-topic-name-for-ar_pose?/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are looking for remapping of topic names. See this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/817/what-is-the-convention-for-topic-name for details.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5